# Unusual MySQL behavior with select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables A, B and C:

- Table A is small (~1000 rows).
- Table B has ~200,000 rows.
- Table C has ~2.2 million rows.

I'm running a query like this:

```
SELECT A.Id FROM A, B, C 
WHERE A.Id = B.SomeId OR (A.Id = C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue = 'X') 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt';
```

- `A.Id` is the primary key of table A
- `B.SomeId` has an index set up
- **Edit**: `C.SomeId` has an index set up
- `C.SomeVal` has an index set up too but it's a VARCHAR(1) with only two possible values

I thought this would only have to iterate over each `Id` in table A (1000 rows) and then potentially query across the other tables (depending on whether MySQL short circuits, I don't know if it does).

But the query seems to hang, or at least it's taking a very long time. Much longer than I would have expected if it only had to iterate 1000 rows. 10 minutes in and the output file is still empty. Let me know if I can provide any more information.

```
my@laptop$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.3
```

**Edit**:
The result I'm looking for is 'Give me all the Id's in table A where the Id matches B.SomeId OR <s>ELSE</s> the Id matches C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue equals 'X'.

Comment: Did you realize that you are creating a cartesian plan?

Comment: That where clause looks suspicious to me.  I think you'll end up with a cartesian product.

Comment: The implicit join syntax with three tables and an `Or` statement is surely the issue here.

Comment: Please edit your question to identify exactly what (joins) your query's are intending to create ? You're using the older syntax and this makes it hard to determine if you the join you're looking for is the one you've coded. Can you say in English what you expect.

Comment: @Siyual The implicit join shouldn't have any effect on the execution plan. It's just syntactic sugar. But `OR` in the `WHERE` clause often thwarts use of indexes.

Comment: I would bet this `OR` in the `WHERE` clause should be an `AND` too. Rewritten to `SELECT A.Id FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.Id = B.SomeId INNER JOIN C ON (A.Id = C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue = 'X') INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt';` or the `UNION` as @Matt suggests.

Comment: I think a UNION would be the preferable alternative to this OR in your WHERE clause.

Comment: See the paragraph beginning with _Minimize the OR keywords in your WHERE clauses._ here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html

Comment: @Barmar True, but with three tables, and the `Or` being over the different join conditions, it will definitely cause an issue.  It's a bit hard to visualize what plan the engine might take here.

Comment: All tables are using MYISAM for what it's worth. I don't know what a cartesian plan is, I'll look it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OR` expressions often make it difficult for MySQL to use indexes. Try changing to a `UNION`:

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id = B.SomeID
UNION
SELECT A.id
FROM A
JOIN C ON A.id = C.SomeID
WHERE C.SomeValue = 'A'
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html):

> Minimize the OR keywords in your WHERE clauses. If there is no index that helps to locate the values on both sides of the OR, any row could potentially be part of the result set, so all rows must be tested, and that requires a full table scan. If you have one index that helps to optimize one side of an OR query, and a different index that helps to optimize the other side, use a UNION operator to run separate fast queries and merge the results afterward.

Your query is described by the last sentence: you have different indexes for each side of the `OR` query.

Comment: Wow that's great, I'd hardly lifted my finger off the enter key before it had finished.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how the query works, but is this dropping A.id values when both conditions are satisfied i.e. A.id == B.SomeId AND (A.Id == C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue == 'X') ?

Comment: @Jenn's answer does that, I don't see how mine would. Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @RTF If you have A.id that matches `B.SomeID AND (A.Id == C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue == 'X')` this query will include A.id once. It will not include the duplicated value, but the id will still be a part of your result set.

Comment: I thought he meant it was dropping the value entirely. I don't think he wants duplicates. That's what his _or else_ was about -- he also mentioned short-circuiting in the question, as he thought the query plan would skip testing C if it already found a match in B.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for distinct IDs from table A that match either of the search conditions i.e. X || (Y && Z) - I should have put that in the original edit, it's less confusing

Comment: It was clear to me from the query you attempted. @Jenn is just getting pedantic about your use of language.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, I was just trying to explain. I thought RTF was confused about what your query was doing. As for my interpretation of the language, the question was edited to include (what I thought) was an exclusive or halfway through when I was writing my answer. There is no need to be disrespectful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go even smaller. Let's say that your tables look like this:

> ```
> A.ID
> 1
> 2
>
> B.SomeID
> 1
> 3
>
> C.SomeID | C.SomeValue
> 1        |   X
> 2        |   X
> ```

Now, let's see what your query will do. First, we look to see if A.ID match and B.SomeID match. In the case of A.ID = 1, we have a match! Sql short circuits. This means that if the first part of your `or` is true, sql doesn't evaluate the 2nd part of your `or`. Now, we still have to join with table C. Since there is no join condition, for table C sql matches A.ID with all the columns in table C.

Now we need to compare A.ID with the next row in B. Well, 1 <> 3. So, we move on to the second part of the `or`. When C.SomeID = 1, the row is included. When C.SomeID = 2, the row is not included. Your results for A.ID = 1 are:

> ```
> A.ID    | B.SomeID   | C.SomeID   | C.SomeValue
> 1       | 1          | 1          |  X
> 1       | 1          | 2          |  X
> 1       | 3          | 1          |  X
> ```

This is clearly not the results table that you are looking for. Since you are going to join A with either table B or C, instead of an `or`, you should use a `union`

```
SELECT A.Id FROM A, B
WHERE A.Id = B.SomeId

Union All

Select A.ID From A, C
 Where A.Id = C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue = 'X'
```

Union all puts the results from the first query into the same results table as the results from the second query. Now, your question says that you only want the A.IDs that are in one table but not the other (or else). There are several ways to do this. In this case, I am going to use a `having` and a subquery. You could also use a `not exists` but I believe that `having` is going to use less resources.

```
Select T.ID
From
(SELECT A.Id FROM A, B
WHERE A.Id = B.SomeId

Union All

Select A.ID From A, C
Where A.Id = C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue = 'X') T
Group By T.ID
Having count(1) = 1
```

We only want the Ids that show up exactly one time. This will only work if the id is not repeated in B or C, so keep that in mind. Since the condition is based on the aggregate function, count, this stipulation must be in the `having`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the `COUNT()` condition, but it needs a `GROUP BY` to go along with it.

Comment: I think you may be reading too much into _or else_ in the question. I doubt he means it as _exclusive or_.

Comment: @Barmar Whoops, you're right. I explained why I'm using a count in my answer. The OP wanted only the A.IDs that matched with B.SomeID `Or Else` matched with C.SomeID. Or Else has a very specific meaning.

Comment: Perhaps, but if the OP doesn't want the exclusive or, it should not be included in the question. Plus it's in caps, so I interpreted it as a developer.

Comment: I don't. Both conditions matching is fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not strong in MySQL, but I think this would work better:

```
SELECT Id FROM
( SELECT A.Id FROM A, B
  WHERE A.Id = B.SomeId
  UNION
  SELECT A.Id FROM A, C 
  WHERE A.Id = C.SomeId AND C.SomeValue = 'X'
) X
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt';
```

Comment: the second `SELECT` of the `UNION` shouldn't include those A.id values from the A JOIN B part. Add a LEFT JOIN to the first one :-)

Comment: @VMai Unless you say `UNION ALL`, it defaults to `UNION DISTINCT`, which removes duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar You're right of course. He's selecting only ids.